# Is there any practical difference between these two definitions of type-level Peano Natural number summation?

Tags: haskell, types, typechecking, dependent-type

I'm new to type level programming, and I am facing inability to reason about even very simple type level programs.

I have this code:

```
data Nat = Zero | Succ Nat

type family n + m where
    Zero + m = m  -- This is the base case of my type level recursive function.
```

Now, I have two variants of going about recursive case, and only one of them typechecks without `UndecidableInstances`:

```
    Succ n + m = n + Succ m  -- Typechecks with UndecidableInstances.

    Succ n + m = Succ (n + m)  -- Typechecks without UndecidableInstances.
```

I understand that `UndecidableInstances` allow me to use general recursion on type level, rather than structural recursion alone, which would guarantee typechecker termination. But in actuality both definitions seem to compile equally well, and give sane types when verified with `:kind!` in repl, for small numbers.

Can I be certain that these two definitions are equivalent in all regards, or are there corner cases? Should I test these implementations of `+` against each other, or use some theory?

Comment: "Can I be certain that these two definitions are equivalent in all regards, or are there corner cases?" A type checker like Haskell's is concerned with _definitional equality_ - "do these two types match syntactically"? Often the way you set up your specifications has an impact on how easy or difficult it is to write code which implements those specifications. Try writing "`++`-on-vectors" using your second definition of `+`.

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson Like this one? `data V (n :: Nat) i = V [i] deriving Show; (%%) :: V n i -> V m i -> V (n + m) i; (V xs) %% (V ys) = V (xs ++ ys)` I think it works.

Comment: With that definition you have no guarantee that the vector in question is in fact the length it says it is. See @KABuhr’s answer

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson How is it that I haven't if I clearly said `... -> V (n + m)` ?

Comment: That function would type check even if you gave it a return type of `V (Succ m) i` or `V (n * m) i` or `V Zero i`. No guarantees about the length

Answer (score 2):

Suppose

```
foo :: T (Succ n) -> Bool
bar :: T n -> T m -> T (n + m)
```

Then,

```
baz :: T (Succ a) -> String
baz x | foo (bar x x) = "A"
      | otherwise     = "B"
```

will only type-check if `+` was defined using

```
Succ n + m = Succ (n + m)
```

If instead we used

```
Succ n + m = n + Succ m
```

then, during the type-checking of `baz`, we would discover that `bar x x :: a + Succ (Succ a)`, but that is not of the right form to be an argument of `foo`.

Summing up: it not enough to think about "[ground](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ground_expression)" `Nat` types. During type checking we also meet with type expressions with free type variables (i.e., non ground) like `Succ a + Succ a`, which will be simplified according to the equational rules. We need rules that work on such cases, too.

Comment: What you're saying is that the second definition is preferable because it is "more definite" or "more specific" in cases where `n` is not "ground"? Also, can you put a definition of "ground" types somewhere in the answer? It is kind of obvious but still I think it's better to write down that `Succ` and `Zero` are "ground" while `a` is not because it can be some other, unrelated type constructor. (Can it? That would mean there are other type constructors of kind `Nat` that the function does not cover, but it is not possible as `Nat`'s definition is closed?)

Comment: @Kindaro In computer science, a "ground" term (or expression) is simply one without free type variables (like `a`). So, `Zero, Succ Zero, Succ (Succ Zero), ...` are all the ground type-terms of kind `Nat`. Instead, `n + Zero` is not ground. It is generally hard to state which definition is preferable -- it depends on how they will be used. Above, I only show they are not equivalent, in general.

Comment: Typically a type family definition whose RHS is constructor-headed is better than one which is not. This is simply because GHC knows many things about constructors (like they are injective and generative) but knows nothing about type families (except how to evaluate them, so if a type family application is stuck, then GHC knows nothing about it).

Answer (score 2):

As others have noted, the two definitions are not equivalent.  Neither is particularly more general than the other, and it would be a stretch to argue that one or the other was clearly superior.

As @Benjamin Hodgson notes, the choice of definition affects the ease with which you can write code, but I'd add that typically each choice will make some code easier and other code harder.

Here's a concrete example.  Suppose you have a vector type:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}

data Nat = Zero | Succ Nat

-- A vector type
data Vec n a where
  V0 :: Vec Zero a
  (:>) :: a -> Vec n a -> Vec (Succ n) a
infixr 5 :>
```

and let's start by working with the "nice" version of `(+)`, the one that doesn't require undecidable instances.  Note that I've switched the order of `m` and `n` because I get confused otherwise:

```
type family m + n where
  Zero + m = m
  Succ m + n = Succ (m + n)
```

If we try to implement a `(++)` for vectors, we find it's straightforward:

```
vappend :: Vec m a -> Vec n a -> Vec (m + n) a
vappend V0 ys = ys
vappend (x :> xs) ys = x :> vappend xs ys
```

On the other hand, consider the following list function:

```
rev :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
rev ys [] = ys
rev ys (x:xs) = rev (x:ys) xs
```

which might be used to define a version of `reverse`:

```
reverse' = rev []
```

If we try to implement `vrev`, we run into trouble:

```
vrev :: Vec m a -> Vec n a -> Vec (n + m) a
vrev ys V0 = ys
vrev ys (x :> xs) = vrev (x :> ys) xs
```

The first case type-checks okay, but the second fails with the complaint that GHC can't deduce:

```
(n1 + 'Succ m) ~ 'Succ (n1 + m)
```

even though this statement is "obviously" true.

Replacing `n + m` with `m + n` in the signature makes things worse -- neither case will type-check.

On the other hand, if you replace the `+` definition with the undecidable version:

```
Succ m + n = m + Succ n
```

you'll find that `vrev` type-checks fine while `vappend` doesn't!

So, what's the solution?  Well, typically people choose a definition that seems the most convenient in the most number of cases and then use various techniques to handle the "hard" cases.  If you choose the:

```
Succ m + n = Succ (m + n)
```

definition, you'll be in good company.  That's the one used in the [Hasochism paper](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/slindley/papers/hasochism.pdf) and the `singletons-nats` package, for example.